# Use Taylor's Theorem with $n=2$ to prove that the inequality $1+x<e^x$ is valid for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ except $x=0$.

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

> Use Taylor's Theorem with $n=2$ to prove that the inequality $1+x<e^x$ is valid for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ except $x=0$.
>
> Taylor's Theorem: 
>   $$
>   f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n{1\over k!}f^{(k)}(c)(x-c)^k+E_n(x) \\
>   \text{where}\quad E_n(x)={1\over (n+1)!}f^{n+1}(\xi)(x-c)^{n+1}
> $$

I'm not sure how to do this. Any solutions or hints are greatly appreciated. I'm not sure if I'm supposed to even use this error term $E_n(x)$ since when $n=2$, $f(x)=e^x$, and $c=0$ we obtain something like $e^x=1+x+{1\over 2}x^2$ and since ${1\over 2}x^2>0$ for all reals except $x=0$ we see that $1+x<e^x$. I'm just confused about how to approach this problem.

Comment: In most statement of Taylor's Theorem, "$n$" refers to the highest power $(x-c)^n$ used in the approximating Taylor polynomial. With that notation, it is much better to use $n=1$. Using $n=2$ makes for trouble in dealing with negative $x$.

Answer (score 2):

I suffices $n=1$ and $c=0$. In this way you get $e^x=1+x+E_1(x)=1+x+\frac{1}{2}e^\xi x^2$. Note that $\frac{1}{2}e^\xi x^2>0$ for all $\xi$ provided $x\neq 0$

Comment: Is the error term independent of the sum in Taylor's Theorem?

Comment: What do you mean by independent? Sorry, I don't understand

Comment: nevermind, I answered my own question

Comment: If $n=2$ would I get $e^x=1+x+{1\over 2}x^2+{1\over 3!}e^{\xi}x^3$?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: So would I just need to show that ${1\over 2}x^2+{1\over 3!}e^{\xi}x^3>0$? Which would imply that $1+x<e^x$.

Comment: You have the result with n=1, why do you need to use n=2? Besides, what you have just written is not true for an arbitrary $\xi$. Note that you don't have any information about $xi$. I think that the right way is with n=1, why do you need complicate the problem? Are you sure that the problem ask you to use n=2? maybe it refers to the order.

Comment: The problem stated to use Taylor's Theorem with $n=2$ to prove the inequality. That's the only reason why I'm doing that.

Answer (score 0):

The Taylor's expansion for $e^x$ at $x_0=0$ (or Maclurent sereis) is 
$$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\dots$$ So for $x\geq 0$ there is no problem. For negetivs the sign of removed terms is agree with the first removed term,then $\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\dots>0$ so $1+x<e^x$.